# Make a replaceAll look once at each char from String (because of for-loop)

Tags: arrays, for-loop, replace

In my program at some point, it asks for an user input and it will after output the same input but with some `replaceAll()`. Here is what I want to do:

Array Table:

```
public static String[][] Alphabet = {

        {"a", "w"}, // 0 0 / 0 1
        {"b", "t"}, // 1
        {"c", "e"}, // 2
        {"d", "k"}, // 3
        {"e", "c"}, // 4
        {"f", "j"}, // 5
        {"g", "h"}, // 6
        {"h", "g"}, // 7
        {"i", "o"}, // 8
        {"j", "f"}, // 9
        {"k", "d"}, // 10
        {"l", "s"}, // 11
        {"m", "q"}, // 12
        {"n", "y"}, // 13
        {"o", "i"}, // 14
        {"p", "u"}, // 15
        {"q", "m"}, // 16
        {"r", "v"}, // 17
        {"s", "l"}, // 18
        {"t", "b"}, // 19
               //etc....
```

Then further down my code:

```
            Scanner Mode1_Input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String mode1_input = new String(Mode1_Input.nextLine());

            if(mode1_input != null && !mode1_input.isEmpty()){
                for(int i = 0; i < 62; i++){ // 62 = [a-z]+[A-Z]+[0-9]
                    mode1_input = mode1_input.replaceAll(Alphabet[i][0], Alphabet[i][1]);

                }
                System.out.println(mode1_input);
                            //etc...
```

The problem is:
'a' will replace by 'w':
so 'a' is now 'w'.
BUT when 'w' comes, it will re-change it to 'a'! :(

Is it possible to make it so it will look at each char once to avoid this annoing change?

**SEE REST OF PROBLEM, LOOK AT THE COMMENTS ON THE POST OF: 'No Idea For Name'**

More code for 'No Idea for Name':

```
    public static String[][] Alphabet = {
            {"a", "1"},
            {"b", "2"},
            {"c", "3"},
            {"d", "4"},
            {"e", "5"},
            {"f", "6"},
            {"g", "7"},
            {"h", "8"},
            {"i", "9"},
            {"j", "10"},
            {"k", "11"},
            {"l", "12"},
            {"m", "13"},
            {"n", "14"},
            {"o", "15"},
            {"p", "16"},
            {"q", "17"},
            {"r", "18"},
            {"s", "19"},
            {"t", "20"},
            {"u", "21"},
            {"v", "22"},
            {"w", "23"},
            {"x", "24"},
            {"y", "25"},
            {"z", "26"},

            {"1", "w"},
            {"2", "t"},
            {"3", "e"},
            {"4", "k"},
            {"5", "c"},
            {"6", "j"},
            {"7", "h"},
            {"8", "g"},
            {"9", "o"},
            {"10", "f"},
            {"11", "d"},
            {"12", "s"},
            {"13", "q"},
            {"14", "y"},
            {"15", "i"},
            {"16", "u"},
            {"17", "m"},
            {"18", "v"},
            {"19", "l"},
            {"20", "b"},
            {"21", "p"},
            {"22", "r"},
            {"23", "a"},
            {"24", "z"},
            {"25", "n"},
            {"26", "x"},
}
... (Skiping Scanner and other...)
for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
                    mode1_input = mode1_input.replaceAll(Alphabet[i][0], Alphabet[i][1]);   
                }
                System.out.println(mode1_input);

Thanks, 3751_Creator
```

Comment: You can use an hashmap to store the Alphabet[i][1] value and check if it is there in the hashmap before doing the replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change 'w' to a different char, maybe to a char that won't be used like anything above 128, and then replace it back after you changed 'a' to 'w'

Comment: The thing is, I NEED to do a > w | w > a, My program is, in short, a encryption ++++ DEcryption prog, so I NEED to have it both ways...

Comment: it is. replaceAll 'w' to char 200, replaceAll 'a' to 'w', replaceAll chare 200 to 'a'

Comment: Took me some time to understand, I'll try. But it will be a bit annoying to do...

Comment: Problem!! Ex: a = 1 and j = 10. It will do a weird fusion. When I type 'alex', I should get: 'wscz', but insted, I get 'wwtctk'.

Answer (score 0):

Use an HashMap and store the Alphabet[i][1] value in it and check if Alphabet[i][0] is already on the hashmap and do the replaceAll. If the value is already in the hashmap it means you have already used it to do the replace so dont do the replace. Else do the replace with Alphabet[i][0] with Alphabet[i][1] and put Alphabet[i][1] in the hashMap

Comment: THIS IS MADNESS.
I'll try :p